# How to write an R function that displays plots sequentially?

Tags: r, plot, prompt, interactive, sequential

I want something similar to the 'plot.lm' functionality.

```
y <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1.5)

mod <- lm(y ~ x)

plot(mod)

Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

I want to create several plots and then display them sequentially - prompting the user to hit  in order to see all the plots.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set `par(ask=TRUE)` before calling `plot()`.   You might want to set it after your first plot, so the user doesn't have to wait for that one.  To be nice, set `par(ask=FALSE)` after your last plot.

Comment: The last sentence is *super important*. The best way to do it is to save the old par, and re-set it automatically using `on.exit`: `oldpar = par(ask = TRUE); on.exit(par(oldpar))`.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution for this that I've found is what plot.lm() does somewhere in the beginning of the function:

```
oask <- devAskNewPage(TRUE);
on.exit(devAskNewPage(oask));
```